# Log into WordPress remotely using Curl

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Crafting a function to remotely log into WordPress. Site A - the target WordPress blog - is on a different server than the script i'm using to remotely login. I'm using curl to initially request wp-login.php and set a cookie then, I'm continuing to post form data and eventually redirect user to the administrator dash panel. I've seen people using wordpress functions to do this but I don't have access to WordPress core since I'm not accessing a blog on the same server as login script.

Here's my script:

WordPress says browser has cookies disabled.

```
    <?php

    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $url = "http://your-domain.com/wp-login.php";
    $cookie = "cookie.txt";

    $postdata = 'log='. $username .'&pwd='. $password .'&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to='. $url .'wp-admin/&testcookie=1';
    //visit the wp-login.php and set the cookie.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec ($ch);

    // 3. Continue loging into wordpress
    $login = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    echo curl_exec($login);


    curl_close($ch);
    // Redirect to the wordpress admin panel
    header('location: http://your-domiain.com/wp-admin/');
    die();
    ?>
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't completely straightforward with cURL. Your problem is that cURL doesn't set cookies on your local browser, it just keeps track of them server side, where it's using them. So when you redirect to Wordpress, you don't actually have the cookies set on your client.

If the blog is on the same domain as the page running the cURL requests, you can parse the cURL result to retrieve the cookies and set them in the browser. If it's on a separate domain, then you're out of luck, since browsers won't let you set cookies for another domain.

Comment: Jeremiah, Thanks for your thorough response. I'm still convinced this is possible. I'll keep investigating. Perhaps CORS is my answer.